# How to make a python to run in linux

Tags: python, linux, proxy, server

Please I am trying to use linux and I have used it on LiveCD and I really want to use it but the main problem that am having about Linux is that on windows I use an application as a server (ip: 127.0.0.1 port: 8080) to connect to the internet on it and I want to use the same proxy on Linux but I don't know how to do that.

I have tried to extract the Windows Executable file and its a python program (.pyc).

I want to ask if there's a way to pack the files together to be used in Linux so that i will still be connecting through the same proxy again.

Comment: Which linux distribution are you using?

Comment: You have a python application that you use as a web proxy on Windows and you want to use it on linux instead?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Are you trying to configure Linux to use a proxy server running on a Windows host somewhere on your network?  Or are you trying to replace the Windows host by running a proxy server on a new Linux host?

Comment: I am confused too... Are you trying to run python on Linux or some application? Linux should have python on it already, so no need to "extract" anything. A Windows app on Linux? What is your question exactly?

Comment: I am trying to use the same application I am using on windows on linux to connect to the internet. The application serves as the server

Comment: if i understand what you have to do is to find the conf file of the application and change the port...